# Adding text string to scraped data

Tags: python, xml, scrapy

I'm currently experimenting with scrapy. I'm scraping a couple of links from a certain webpage and exporting them to an xml file.  The problem is as follows, for sertain sites the links don't contain the full url (eg. example.com/page/abc they scraped links are just the relative path from the page that is scraped (eg. page/abc). Now id like to add the base url to the scraped variable eg.

```
item['link'] = link.select('a/@href').extract() would become something like:
item['link'] = "http://example.com" + link.select('a/@href').extract()
```

So the result will be a full usable url, but the solution above doesn't work (noting is scraped when the string is added, and preferably i'd like scrapy to scrape the full url automatically.

I'm not used to python so the solution can be very simple, but after some reading Scrapy was the recommended spider.

Any toughts?

The current code:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from tutorial.items import MyItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "example-com"
    allowed_domains = ["http://example.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://example.com/page.html",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        links = hxs.select('//div[@class="views-field views-field-title"]')
        items = []
        for link in links:
            item = MyItem()
            item['link'] = link.select('span/a/@href').extract()
            items.append(item)
        for item in items:
            yield item
```

**Update / Additional question**

Is it also possible to put more information in the xml file, eg the number of items scraped, the date the spider run and the domainname and or spidername? I tried to return more variables but that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
items = []
for link in links:
    item = MyItem()
    item['link'] = link.select('span/a/@href').extract()
    items.append(item)
for item in items:
    yield item
```

With this:

```
for link in links:
    item = MyItem()
    url = link.select('span/a/@href').extract()
    item['link'] = allowed_domains[0] + url
    yield item
```

What is a `MyItem()` in this context?

Comment: As far as I know, MyItem() refers to Field() definition in items.py, It is needed for scrapy to work, Im not sure what it is specificaly for.